# What happens if a builder doesn't fully fix a problem, and then the home warranty runs out?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, homeownership

I (US citizen living in the US) have a home warranty on my property. This warranty, like all warranties, expires eventually. I have recently identified an issue that is covered by the warranty. What happens if the builder comes in, assesses the issue, determines it is covered by the warranty, does a subpar job, and then either 1. the issue resurfaces or 2. issues associated with the subpar fix spring up later, after the warranty has expired? Is there any defense for this? Or would I be stuck with needing to pay the repairs at that point?

Comment: In what state is the property?

Comment: The general answer is, you lump it or you sue somebody. The main question is who is responsible, and why do you think they have to solve the problem. The warranty should be irrelevant, except that it may eliminate the need to sue (the builder gets paid to fix his mistakes). Is your question about whether the warranty company can still be held liable? A few details need filling in.